# In knex, how do I change an async/await function to one that uses a .then method?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I'm writing a simple post route in knex.js, that adds a message to a database. At the moment it's an async/await function, but how would I refactor it using a .then block? The code is working, I'm just curious. Code as follows:

```
const todo = req.body.message;
try {
  await db('todos').insert({message: todo});
  res.json({message: 'todo successfully stored'});
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that `async` functions just return a promise, so you can simply remove the `await`

```js
const todo = req.body.message;
try {
  db('todos')
    .insert({message: todo})
    .then((result) => {
      res.json({message: 'todo successfully stored'});
    });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Try & catch are relevant only when using await,

Comment: @felixmosh try/catch is for any exception handling - perhaps the expectation is that `db()` or `.insert` will blow up, or maybe it's extraneous - but still, it's certainly not ONLY used for async/await

Comment: I meant that since in this example the db access is async the try & catch are redundant here. it won't catch exceptions in db. in order to catch such errors you need to attach `.catch` to the promise